# ¿Agregar clave y valor a un objeto con valores en Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios de nuevo acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente, estoy creando un "objeto" desde del back-end para ser manipulado en el front con JS, lo que estoy haciendo es hacer consultas a diferentes tablas en mi base de datos y con estos datos crear un objeto JS de la siguiente manera.

```
public function getCustomData($id)
{
    try {
        $tables = CatAdministrator::where('cat_modules_id', $id)->pluck('table_name');
    
        $data = [];

        foreach($tables as $table) {
            $data = array_merge($data, DB::table($table)->get()->toArray());
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'elements' => $data
        ]);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

El código anterior retorna la siguiente estructura:

```
"elements":[
             {"id":1,"nombre":"Darinel","genero":"Masculino"}
             {"id":2,"nombre":"Darwin","genero":"Masculino"}
           ]
```

**Lo que quiero lograr** es agregar otra clave y valor a cada uno de mis objetos generados quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
  "elements":[
                 {"id":1,"nombre":"Darinel","genero":"Masculino", table: 'genero'} // table es la clave agreada
                 {"id":2,"nombre":"Darwin","genero":"Masculino", table: 'genero}  // table es la clave agreada
             ]
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
public function getCustomData($id)
{
    try {
        $tables = CatAdministrator::where('cat_modules_id', $id)->pluck('table_name');
    
        $data = [];

        foreach($tables as $table) {
            $data = array_merge($data, DB::table($table)->get()->toArray());
            $data = array_merge( (array)$data, array( 'table' => $table)); // agregando esta linea
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'elements' => $data
        ]);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Pero esto me retorna la siguiente estructura:

```
"elements": {"0":{id":1,"nombre":"Darinel","genero":"Masculino"},"table":"catalogos_empleados_genero"}}
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo resolver mi problema?

De ante mano les doy las gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios.

**Función actualizada:**

```
public function getCustomData($id)
{
    try {
        $tables = CatAdministrator::where('cat_modules_id', $id)->pluck('table_name');
    
        $data = [];
        
        foreach($tables as $table) {
            $tempArray = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
            foreach(array_keys($tempArray) as $key){
                $tempArray[$key]['table'] = $table;
            }
            $data = array_merge($data, $tempArray);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'elements' => $data,
        ]);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿la tabla que se agrega es correlativa? ¿o qué criterio se usaría para cada tabla en cada "persona"?

Comment: Se generan varias tablas y a estas tablas se les hace la consulta dentro del forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Al trabajar con objetos puedes agregar elementos de forma muy simple

```
$objeto->nuevo_elemento = "valor";
```

Al trabajar con arreglos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$arreglo['nuevoElemento'] = "valor";
```

En tu caso podrías hacer lo siguiente dentro del foreach

```
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $tempArray = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
    foreach(array_keys($tempArray) as $key){
        $tempArray[$key]['table'] = $table;
    }
    $data = array_merge($data, $tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato ya había intentado con la respuesta que me propones el problema es que me retorna con esta estructura "elements":{"0":{"id":1,"nombre":"Darinel","genero":"Masculino"},"table":"catalogos_empleados_genero"} el objeto añadido esta fuera del objeto.

Comment: Estás utilizando el $tempArray cómo lo puse? Si lo haces después del merge entonces si lo pondrá afuera del arreglo pero si lo haces antes del merge lo pondría adentro

Comment: Asíes acabo de copiar tu código tal cual me lo propones sigue con el mismo comportamiento  si me agrega el objeto pero de la siguiente manera {"success":true,"elements":{"0":{"id":1,"nombre":"Darinel","genero":"Masculino"},"table":"catalogos_empleados_genero"}}

Comment: He igual he intentado de las siguientes maneras $data = array_merge($data, $tableArray); y  $data = $data + $tableArray;

Comment: puedes hacer dd($tempArray) después de que se asigna $table y antes de array_merge? Me parece que ya entendí que pasa, tu quieres agregar "table" a todos los elementos del arreglo de cada tabla, cierto?

Comment: Exactamente quiero agregar una nueva propiedad a cada objeto que se itera en el forEach dd($temArray) me devuelve lo siguiente array:2 [
  0 => {#1903
    +"id": 1
    +"nombre": "Darinel"
    +"genero": "Masculino"
  }
  "table" => "catalogos_empleados_genero"
]

Comment: Ok, pero por ahora la tabla catalogos_empleados_genero sólo tiene un elemento? Si tuvieras por ejemplo 5 empleados entonces el arreglo devolvería 5 elementos, cierto?

Comment: Es correcto puede a ver n registros así como también los datos pueden venir de diferentes tablas y por eso necesito el campo table para saber de donde viene cada registro. La idea al final de esto es que ese objeto lo voy a transformar en un array que tenga esta estrucutura ["catalogos_empleados_genero: Darinel Masculino", "catalogos_empleados_genero: Otro registro"]

Comment: Ok, modifiqué el código para que itere sobre todos los elementos del arreglo que contiene los elementos de la tabla y agregue el nombre de la tabla a cada elemento, puse un nuevo foreach para hacer eso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132980/discussion-between-heytalepazguato-and-darinel-cigarroa).

Comment: Me marca error al intentar agregar la ultima actualización de tu respuesta el error es el siguiente "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" también he actualizado la pregunta de como va quedando la función para que este un poco más claro como va el código.

Comment: Entra al chat que cree, el link esta arriba de tu último comentario

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás queriendo agregar el key value después de haber "mergeado".
Puedes preparar los objetos antes de unirlos todos en el array.

```
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $dataFromThisTable = array_merge(DB::table($table)->get()->toArray(), array('table' => $table));
    $data = array_merge($data, $dataFromThisTable);
}
```